# UITableView RegisterNib func is called, however awakeFromNib func is never called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinib

Here is the snippet for register nib:

```
[tableView registerNib:[self returnNib] forCellReuseIdentifier:identifier];
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
```

then here is the snippet from awakeFrom nib:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self setupCellStyle];
}
```

and here my own method returning the nib

```
+ (UINib *)returnNib {
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
    NSString *pathForResource = [bundle pathForResource:NSStringFromClass([self class])  ofType:@"nib"];
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([self class]) bundle:bundle];
    return nib;
}
```

Comment: Also show ```[self returnNib]```

Comment: PS : Could be registered elsewhere already ... you need to move the setup code to ```prepareForReuse``` typically.

Comment: @skaak   I have prepare for `prepareForReuse ` as well just never gets hot

Comment: Problem lies elsewhere I am sure ... either the identifier is not what you think or the nib is not what you think ... look there or show more code

Comment: `+ (UINib *) returnNib
{
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
    NSString *pathForResource = [bundle pathForResource:NSStringFromClass([self class])  ofType:@"nib"];

UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([self class]) bundle:bundle];
    return nib;
}`

Comment: The cell does get rendered, The issue is that the following functions `prepareForReuse ` and `awakeFromNib` are not being hit

Comment: Maybe the problem is you use instance method for ```returnNib``` but declare it as class method? Just check and be sure ```[self returnNib]``` is what you expect it to be it looks a bit weird.

Comment: change the "`+`" of that returnNib method to "`-`" or call it `[[self class] returnNib]` when you want to keep it as is. (ps: you may have to expose a declaration in your header file)

Comment: My bad we had another class that overrides `awakeFromNib` in its extension for some peculiar reasons, I am a bit flustered by that implementation, but latest I know where the problem is, Thanks so much for your help guys!